# How to sort a 2D array by rows and store indices in new 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, np.argsort

I have an array of dimension (43, 25520).

I want to sort them for every of those 43 columns and then store the sorted indices for every row in a new 2d array. So the output should be a new sorted (43, 25520).

```
first_sorted = np.argsort(active_genevector[2,:])
```

With that I get the sorted 25520 indices of the first of 43 rows.

How can I do that to get in the end it for all 43 as a (43, 25520) array?

Comment: I might get the question wrong, because I don't understand, why your output only has 42 columns, but `numpy.argsort` has a `axis` attribute. With that you can just use the function on the whole 2D-Array and sort by axis.

Comment: oh it's a typo.. the output should be (43, 25520)

Comment: OK, and btw. with the way you use `np.argsort()` above, you would get the second row not the first of your big 2D array, as indices start at zero.

Comment: a sure! How can I sort over each axis, and get the big array in the end? I just found argsort(axis = x) and then I can sort for the x axis..

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it helps. The output array `result` has the same dimension as the input array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a short script to test what you need:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.random.random((43,25520))

result = np.argsort(test, axis = 1)

print(result.shape)
```

I think this would work for you.

Comment: nope sadly that's the wrong output.  result[2,:] is another output than my first_sorted..

Comment: Yep, I made a mistake myself, edited it, now it should work (axis should be 1)